# SQL join query for a view with sum of columns across 3 tables

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables as below

```
    Table - travel_requests
    id  industry_id travel_cost stay_cost   other_cost
    1   2           1000        500         200
    2   4           4000        100         200
    3   5           3000        0           400
    4   1           3000        250         100
    5   1           200         100         75

    Table - industry_tech_region
    id  industry_name
    1   Auto
    2   Aero
    3   Machinery
    4   Education
    5   MTV

    Table - industry_allocation
    id  industry_id allocation
    1   1           500000
    2   2           300000
    3   3           500000
    4   4           300000
    5   5           500000
    6   1           200000
```

I want to create a view which has 3 columns

```
industry_name, total_costs, total_allocation
```

I created a view as below

```
SELECT  industry_tech_region.industry_name,     
    SUM(travel_requests.travel_cost + travel_requests.stay_cost + travel_requests.other_cost) AS total_cost,
    SUM(industry_allocation.allocation) AS total_allocation
FROM  industry_tech_region 
  INNER JOIN industry_allocation 
      ON industry_tech_region.id = industry_allocation.industry_id 
  INNER JOIN travel_requests 
      ON industry_tech_region.id = travel_requests.industry_id
GROUP BY industry_tech_region.industry_name
```

But the result I get is as below which is incorrect

```
industry_name   total_cost  total_allocation
Aero            1700        300000
Auto            7450        1400000 (wrong should be 3725 and 700000)
Education       4300        300000
MTV             3400        500000
```

This is probably happening because there are 2 entries for industry_id 1 in the travel_requests table. But they should be counted only once.

Please let me know how do we correct the view statement.

Also I want to add another column in view which is remaining_allocation which is difference of total_allocation and total_cost for each industry.

Comment: Well, what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shoud join  the sum  (and not sum the join)

```
  select          
      a.industry_name
      , t1.total_cost 
      , t2.total_allocation 
  from dbo.industry_tech_region  a
  left join  (
    select dbo.travel_requests.industry_id
      , SUM(dbo.travel_requests.travel_cost + dbo.travel_requests.stay_cost + dbo.travel_requests.other_cost) AS total_cost
    FROM bo.travel_requests
    group by dbo.travel_requests.industry_id
  )  t1 on a.id = t1.industry_id 
  left join (
    select  dbo.industry_allocation.industry_id 
     , SUM(dbo.industry_allocation.allocation) AS total_allocation
    from  dbo.industry_allocation 
    group by dbo.industry_allocation.industry_id   

  ) t2 on a.id = t2.industry_id
```

this happen because you have two entry for the industry_id 1  and then the row are joined  two  time  if you use the subquery for aggreated  the row this can't happen  ...

I have used left join because seems that not all the industry_id match  for the 3 tables ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach too (without the `ORDER BY` because views do not allow it).

```
;WITH q AS (
SELECT industry_id
    , sum(allocation) AS total_allocation
FROM #industry_allocation
GROUP BY industry_id
)
SELECT  #industry_tech_region.industry_name
    , isnull(SUM(#travel_request.travel_cost
     + #travel_request.stay_cost
     + #travel_request.other_cost),0.0) AS total_cost
    ,q.total_allocation AS total_allocation
FROM  #industry_tech_region 
    LEFT JOIN q ON #industry_tech_region.id = q.industry_id 
    LEFT JOIN #travel_request ON #industry_tech_region.id = #travel_request.industry_id
GROUP BY #industry_tech_region.industry_name,q.total_allocation
ORDER BY industry_name
```